# Do I need to know about second order differential equations to solve this problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $V$ is the vector space of all infinitely differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $W$ be the subspace of the functions which are solutions to the IVP

$$f'' + 4f = 0$$
$$f(\pi)=0$$

I need to determine the dimension of $W$. The immediate solution that comes to my mind is trivial: Find the kernel of the linear operator $L$ on $V$ given by
$$L(f) = f''+4f$$

and consider its subspace of all $f$ such that $f(\pi) = 0$. My question is do I need to solve that equation, because I don't know how to solve second order equations. Above that, can this problem have a solution using only techniques of linear algebra?

EDIT: Following Dr. Sonnhard Graubner's comment, I verified the solution using Wolfram Alpha, and the solution comes out to be of the form $$a\sin(2x)+b\cos(2x)$$

However,  for $f(\pi) =0$, $f$ has to be of the form $a\sin(2x)$. Hence,  the dimension of $W$ comes out to be $1$.

Comment: do you know how to solve linear first order systems with constant coefficients?

Comment: $f(\pi)$ being zero should make you suspicious that the answer is going to involve trigonometric functions and provide you with two easy guesses for possible solutions...

Comment: @Thomas, I haven't worked with systems of differential equations before, so no...

Comment: @postmortes, sure, I do know that the $\sin$ function satisfies a similar looking equation, but beyond that, I can't really guess anything.

Comment: You may be able to prove that there is a unique solution for any given value of $f'(\pi)$, even without being able to find the solution.

Comment: $W$ is subspace of $V$ right ?

Comment: @123 Yes, I have not included the proof.

Comment: @codetalker Is $\dim W = 2$ ?

Comment: @123, I don't have the solution, so I don't know

Comment: HINT: the solution is given by $y(x)=C_1\sin (2x)+C_2\cos(2x)$

Comment: @codetalker given the thread in the comments above, it doesn’t seem like there’s an obvious way of solving this without actually solving the ODE. Good thing there is a simple way to solve [linear homogeneous ODEs with constant coefficients](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~moose/240S2013/slides8-05.pdf).

Comment: @Theoretical Economist,  apparently the problem is from a linear algebra book, and the author seems to pretend that the reader is not well versed with calculus.  That led me to thinking that maybe theres a way..  But anyways as it is, thankz for the remark.

Comment: My experience with LA books is that they will assume no understanding of calculus, but throw in a few exercises here and there for the readers that do. After all, how can you even know what an ODE is if you are not at least somewhat well-versed in calculus?

Comment: Any thoughts on the answer I posted the other day, codetalker?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure linear algebra proof, requiring no knowledge of how to solve differential equations.

Differentiating the differential equation $n-2$ times, we get $f^{(n)}+4f^{(n-2)}=0$, so $f^{(n)}(\pi)=-4f^{(n-2)}(\pi)$. Thus, if we know $f'(\pi)$, then we know $f^{(n)}(\pi)$ for all $n$ (remember that we know $f(\pi)=0$). Therefore, if we know $f'(\pi)$, then we know the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $\pi$, which means we know $f$. So, the space of all solutions is one-dimensional, as it just depends on the one parameter, $f'(\pi)$.